# How to get the 'entry point' of a program in ruby file?

Tags: ruby, module, path

I have three ruby files, `a.rb`, `b.rb` and `c.rb` as followings:

To execute the `c.rb` I could either `ruby a.rb` or `ruby lib/lib/c.rb`. But I want to distinguish this two method. So in `c.rb` I want to know the entry point of the program. (if you are familiar with node, it is the same as `require.main`.)

```
dir
 -- a.rb
 -- lib
    -- b.rb
    -- lib
       -- c.rb

# a.rb
require 'lib/b'

# b.rb
require 'lib/c'

# c.rb
puts 'I am here'
```

Answer (score 4):

The classic way of doing it is with `__FILE__` and `$0` :

```
if $0 == __FILE__
  # code when this file is the entry point
end
```

Comment: what if I want to know how `b.rb` is loaded in the program?

Comment: You could test for the presence of classes or modules that you want to use instead of testing of a specific file is loaded. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?